# How can I get the minicart to always show?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend, mini-cart

I'm working on a design which has the minicart always visible (instead of only when you click on the cart image in the header).

**How can I get the minicart to always show?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mini-cart's is always there, it's just hidden with CSS, `display:none`.

I can't remember the CSS class of the mini-cart's content, but you can find it with your browser inspector an then In your theme override the `display: none;` CSS with:

`display: block !important;`.

Comment: I was trying to find the template file to avoid the !important but this might be generated through JS, so your solution should be easier. It works, thank you

Comment: Yes KnockoutJS is generating the much of the templates for this section and some other JS is setting the display none inline. This was the approach that I used

Comment: this is the phtml template file for it `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`